# HTTP retry change url's parameter

Tags: javascript, angular, http

I have created an retry function which can be called when an requests fail so that it can retry it. The idea is that a request would fail when an user's token is expired, so when if it is expired, it should refresh the token and retry with the new one, but it retries still with the OLD one. Have no idea what to do in order for the retry to take in consideration the new value.

This is the retry function :

```
http_retry(maxRetry: number = 5, delayMs: number = 2000) {
        return (src: Observable<any>) => src.pipe(
            retryWhen(_ => {
                return interval(delayMs).pipe(
                    flatMap(count => count == maxRetry ? throwError("Giving up") : of(this.authService.refreshToken()))
                )
            })
        )
}
```

So this would refresh the token value(It actually gives and stores the new value but it does not use it in the retried requests)

This is the function which does the request :

```
myRequest(){
        return this.http.get<any[]>(
            `${this.url}?auth=${this.authService.getUserValue().token}`
        );
}
```

And here is how I call the request with the retry :

```
this.myRequest()
   .pipe(this.http_retry())
   .subscribe(resData => {
      // Logic code
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By executing `http.get`, you create an Observable, which, when subscribed to, will make a new HTTP GET request to the url which was passed to `http.get`.**

In your code, you only ever execute `http.get` once, and then `retryWhen` merely creates a new Subscription to this same source Observable for each retry.

You can use the `switchMap` operator to achieve your desired result. Simply change `myRequest` to the following:

```
myRequest() {
    return of(this.url).pipe(
        switchMap(url => this.http.get<any[]>(
           `${url}?auth=${this.authService.getUserValue().token}`
        ))
    )
}
```

This way the source is an Observable which emits the url (without the token in it).

On each retry a new subscription gets made, and the following will then happen.

1. The source Observable emits the url.
2. The url gets piped into `switchMap`.
3. `switchMap` ***creates a new Observable*** by calling `http.get` with the current value of the token, and returns this new Observable.
4. Subscribing to the Observable causes it to make a request to the url passed into `http.get`, and emit the response.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Will try it a bit later and will come with an response